# Minimum number of elements needed to satisfy a property for all choices of $c \le \binom{n}{2}$ couples from $n$ sets.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $n$ finite distinct sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n \subset [q] = \{1, \ldots, q\}, A_1,\ldots,A_n \not= \emptyset$ and $c \le \binom{n}{2}$ unordered couples of them chosen arbitrarily among the $\binom{n}{2}$ possible, provided that the intersection of the two sets in the couple is empty.

$A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are not given, but can be chosen at will. They will be chosen with the goal of minimizing $q$ given $n$ and $c$, for all possible choices of the $c$ couples. Maybe it is more clear to ask that $q$ be the minimum over all choices of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ and the $c$ couples, given $n$ and $c$.

If for example $c = \binom{n}{2}$ we can take $q = n$ singleton sets each with a different element and we cannot do less than that, but I find it difficult to figure out how to proceed in the general case $c \lt \binom{n}{2}$.

Another example is $n=5$ and $c \le 5$. In this case we have a minimum $q = 3$ that we can obtain for $1 \le c \le 5$ using e.g. $A_1 = \{1\}$, $A_2 = \{2\}$, $A_3 = \{3\}$, $A_4 = \{1,2\}$, $A_5 = \{1,3\}$. But with $n=5$ and $c = 6$ the minimum is $q = 4$ obtained with e.g. $A_1 = \{1\}$, $A_2 = \{2\}$, $A_3 = \{3\}$, $A_4 = \{4\}$, $A_5 = \{1,2\}$. Choose the disjoint couples as you want.

We can always take the lowest value of $q$ such that $\binom{q}{2} \ge c$, then make $q$ singleton sets and build the other $n-q$ easily without the need for them to be disjoint, but the actual minimum of $q$ is lower.

Any hint for a general lower bound for $q$?

I am particularly interested in the case $n=39$ and $c=113$.

Comment: It never hurts to use singleton sets, since if $A\cap B=\varnothing$ removing elements does not change the result. If you are considering all ways to choose the couples, and the $A_i$ are fixed regardless of how the choice of couples varies, then all $A_i$ must be pairwise disjoint, since a couple could potentially link any pair of sets, and $q=n$ always. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel, no I don't agree. Basically I want the minimum of $q$ over all $A_1, \ldots A_n$ and $c$ couples taken from them, but it is enough that the $q$ elements are enough to build a specific $A_1, \ldots A_n$ plus specific $c$ couples of them. It is like enumerating all possible configurations $A_1, \ldots A_n$ plus $c$ couples, let's call that configuration $i$, then find $q_i$ min, then $q$ is the min over all $q_i$. And note that there can be a configuration $i$ with $n$ sets and $c_i$ couples and another $j$ with $n$ sets and $c_j\not=c_i$ couples, with maybe $q_j\not=q_i$.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel please tell me if it is clearer now, or if I am missing something on the problem that I have in mind.

Comment: The thing is that two sets $A_p$ and $A_q$ that do not form a couple can have a non-empty intersection, therefore we can reuse elements.

Comment: I suppose you want this: given $n$ and $c$, what is the least $q$ so that for all possible couple arrangements an assignment of the $A_i$ can be made from $[q]$ satisfying the disjoint condition?

Comment: Your thinking is confused. You seem to be implying by your examples that you can choose the contents of each $A_i$ first and then the couples. But your problem statement implies that you choose the couples first and then the contents of $A_i$.

Comment: In particular, when $n=5$ and $c=5$, if the couples are chosen before the sets $A_i$ then it is not possible to have $q=3$. Choose the couples $\{A_1,A_2\}$, $\{A_2,A_3\}$, $\{A_3,A_4\}$, $\{A_4,A_5\}$, $\{A_1,A_5\}$. There are only three singleton sets, so some $A_i$ will be a pair like $\{1,2\}$. But there is only one nonempty subset of $[q]$ disjoint from the pair, and $A_i$ is supposed to be disjoint from two subsets.

Comment: Actually it is like we extract from a lottery a ticket with $n$ specific sets and $c$ couples of them with a universe of size $q$. The only thing that is known in advance is $n$ and $c$, the rest is extracted at random. Then we want to compute the minimum of $q$ over all possible tickets of the lottery.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov sets and couples are "extracted" together. For my original problem it is bad to have a low value of $q$ so I want to find a configuration where $q$ is the lowest possible to find my worst case, hoping it is big enough for me.

Comment: Ok, so both the sets *and* the couples are chosen by you, given $n$ and $c$. In other words, given $n$ and $c$ we want the least $q = q(n,c)$ such that there exist distinct nonempty subsets $A_1, \dots, A_n \subseteq [q]$ among which at least $c$ pairs are disjoint.

Comment: But if the sets and couples are extracted at the same time, there is nothing to optimise over!

Comment: @Parcly Taxel optimised over all possible extractions. I have canceled the OK to your previous interpretation because I said OK not reading it carefully, sorry.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I want to find the minimum $q$ over all the sets and couples in the world. Yes at least $c$ pairs. I think your formulation is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid set-couple combo for $n$ and $c$ with $A_i\subseteq[q]$ corresponds to a subgraph with $n$ vertices and $c$ edges of $G_q$, a graph on $2^q-1$ vertices representing the nonempty subsets of $[q]$ where edges link any and all disjoint subset pairs. The number of edges in $G_q$ is
$$\frac12\sum_{i=1}^q\binom qi(2^{q-i}-1)=S(q+1,3)$$
where $S$ is the second-kind Stirling number. Therefore $n\le2^q-1$ and $c\le S(q+1,3)$.

$G_q$ may be *approximately* tested for a subgraph of the given order and size through a greedy algorithm: add vertices for subsets of increasing size to the putative subgraph until $n$ vertices have been added. If the induced subgraph has at least $c$ edges, return YES, else NO. The algorithm is not exact since for larger $q$ the highest-degree vertices in $G_q$ correspond to non-singleton subsets, but it should be a good approximation.

For $n=39,c=113$ we need $q\ge6$, but the first two "levels" of $G_6$ with all the singetons and pairs provide a subgraph with $21$ vertices and $120$ edges, more than enough:

- $15$ edges between singletons
- $45$ edges between pairs
- $60$ edges from singletons to pairs

Thus $q(n=39,c=113)=6$, with $21$ of the $A_i$ being all the singletons and pairs and the remaining $A_i$ being arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it might be worthwhile to ask another question with a possible additional constraint that I have thought meanwhile, i.e. $|A_i| \ge 3, i=1,\ldots,n$, and hope for minimum $q \gt 13$ for $n=39$ and $m=113$, or is it hopeless?

Comment: See also the comments by Misha Lavrov below his answer, $q = 8$ in that case.

Answer (score 1):

A setup like $n=39$ and $c=113$ is sparse: there are $\binom{39}{2} = 741$ pairs of subsets, and we only want a small fraction of them to be disjoint.

In this case, the following strategy seems to be a good idea. First, $q=5$ will not be enough, since there are at most $2^5-1 = 31$ sets to pick in that case. So we must take $q \ge 6$. With $q=6$, just list all the nonempty subsets of $\{1,\dots,q\}$ in order first by size (since we prefer to pick smaller sets) and then arbitrarily, and pick the first $39$ of them.

According to Mathematica, if we pick all the $1$-element and $2$-element sets, all the $3$-element sets containing $1$ or $2$ (which brings us up to $37$), and finally the sets $\{3,4,5\}$ and $\{3,4,6\}$, then $236$ of these are disjoint, which is comfortably over the threshold of $c=113$. So $q=6$ is the optimal solution.

---

In the dense case, where $c$ is a majority of $\binom n2$, Alon and Frankl's paper [The maximum number of disjoint pairs in a family of subsets](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02582924) suggests the following strategy, which they prove to be asymptotically optimal.

Choose the least $k\ge2$ such that $(1 - \frac1k)\binom n2 \ge c$. Then, we take $q = k \lceil \log_2 (\frac nk+1) \rceil$. Now, the set $\{1, 2, \dots, q\}$ can be divided into $k$ disjoint subsets $X_1, \dots, X_k$ such that $2^{|X_i|}-1 \ge \frac nk$ for all $i$.

To choose our family, we take $\lfloor \frac nk\rfloor$ or $\lceil\frac nk\rceil$ subsets of each $X_i$. We'll get approximately $(1 - \frac1k) \binom n2$ disjoint pairs just from the fact that any subset of $X_i$ is disjoint from any subset of $X_j$ with $i\ne j$. Maybe we'll lose a few because of rounding up or down, but on the other hand we'll gain a few because of disjoint pairs within each $X_i$. In the end, we should get at least $c$ disjoint pairs.

Comment: Thank you, I am thinking if asking another question with an additional constraint, see the above comment below Parcly Taxel answer.

Comment: You will not get $q>13$ even with that restriction. We can easily do $q=10$: there are $16$ different subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we can take and $16$ different subsets of $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$, for $256$ disjoint pairs in the first $32$ sets (and then throw in $7$ more arbitrarily). I expect we can do $q=9$, maybe even less.

Comment: In fact, $q=8$ is possible: a random sample of $39$ of the $3$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ seems to consistently get around $130$ disjoint pairs. Also, $q=8$ is the best we can do, since there are only $105$ disjoint pairs among *all* the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ with $3$ or more elements.